# overcoming little-endian-ness when union'ing char[4] with int32

Tags: c, endianness, unions

On my little-endian z80-esque processor I have a 32-bit `long int msk = 0xFFFFFF00` (Subnet Mask).
I learned about endian-ness this morning when I tried passing
`(unsigned char *)&msk` to a
`void bar(unsigned char * c);` function that walks through the values of this `&msk` and stores them to a database.

Unfortunately due to the little-endian-ness of z80 processors, the database stores the values "backwards", and when another function reads the bytes back, it sees `0x00FFFFFF`, which is not the correct subnet mask.

Is there any trivial way around this with unions? I'd like `char[3]` to map to the LSB of my `long int msk`, instead of what it currently is (`char[0]` gets the LSB).

In conclusion, Big-Endian is better.

Comment: There are many answers on stackoverflow about converting big endian to little endian, and vice versa. Have you tried any of those approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix endian issues: Whenever you serialize your integers to disk or to the network, convert them to a known byte order. Network order aka big-endian, is the easiest because the htonl and htons functions already exist. Or you may do it manually by repeatedly pulling off the low-order byte with `byte & 0xFF; byte >>= 8` or the high-order byte with `((byte >> i*8) & 0xFF)`

If you have a `long int` value and want the LSB of it, it is far more portable to use bit shift and mask operations rather than unions or casts.

Answer (score 1):

`ntohl` will swap the endianess of a 32-bit integer

Comment: Just a note: `ntohl` does absolutely nothing if you are running on a big-endian system. So you cannot use it for generic byte swapping.

Comment: I think that, more specifically, `htonl` will always convert longs to big-endianness, and `ntohl` will always convert longs to whatever the system uses. This makes them cross-compatibile.

Comment: Weird on my system it was reversible, ie ntohl(ntohl(data))=data.

Comment: thanks, those are great functions. Unfortunately I don't access to them so I suppose I'll just implement my own!

Comment: @asbumste: They are reversible because the functions do not know the byte order of the integer: they trust the programmer to know. And big-endian to little-endian is reversible either way. I don't think some rare ones like PDP-endian are reversible.